# Angular: Setting Styles on @Component dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-components

Angular 13

On my **@Component** I have this set up for **dynamic values**. Doesn't work

```
styles: [
    `
        .k-daterangepicker .k-dateinput {
            width: {{myWidth}};
        }
    `,
],
```

How do I change *.k-daterangepicker .k-dateinput* to a dynamic width for the @Component only?

Comment: [Angular reference](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding). `@HostBinding('style.width.px') get size() { return 450; }`. Not in the component decorator, but inside the component class itself

Comment: I am looking to change the definition of this CSS classes selector:"  .k-daterangepicker .k-dateinput"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your component template looks something like this:

```html
<div class="k-daterangepicker k-dateinput">
    ...
</div>
```

you can add a style binding like this:

```html
...
<div class="k-daterangepicker k-dateinput" [style.width]="inputWidth">
    ...
</div>
...
```

and in your typescript code for the template, you can change your `inputWidth` property in several different ways (one example follows):

```js
...
export class MyComponent {
    @Input() inputWidth: string = '450px'; // Defaults to 450px
    ...
}
```

Comment: how about if we are not allowed to add style inline? What I mean is there any way to make width: {{myWidth}}; dynamic in which we can assign myWidth in the component only?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but inside `MyComponent`, you have `inputWidth` as a public property that is also marked as an `Input` so you can dynamically change this value either inside the `my-component.component.ts` file or from a parent component's template using the `Input` binding syntax.  '450px' is just the default value in case you decide not to set the width to anything at first.

If this doesn't answer you question, please feel free to re-word it another way

Comment: Let's say that your component has two div children of the main div, the first child has ".first" class, and the second child has ".second" class. Let say that in each class there's a dynamic property. How can we do that?